# CSS to make heading responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a heading on my website responsive so it's smaller on mobile and doesn't wrap. I looked up the code to use but it's not working. Can someone please tell me why? Thanks

I've added a div class and then referenced it in a media query but it doesn't do anything.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .contact-heading {
    font-size: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3 class="contact-heading">CONTACT FLOWERS FOR EVERYONE</h3>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: it works perfectly fine for me, but you forgot to close your media query.

Comment: No sorry there was more stuff in that media query. It is closed at the bottom. What device are you viewing it on? I'm viewing on an Samsung S9 and I see no change?

Comment: @Michelle — The live demo in the question demonstrably works as you can click Expand snippet and then adjust the size of a desktop browser window to see the text change size.

Comment: I see it now! Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use this formula: https://websemantics.uk/tools/responsive-font-calculator/ . check the minimum font-size for mobile then the font-size for desktop. the formula auto adjusts the font size based on viewport and you no longer need media queries